# Reduce results to only those with more than 1 unique row based on a single field

Tags: sql, duplicates, field, unique, rows

My data looks something like this...

```
Table A

Name                 Phone
--------------------------------------
Bobs Place           111111111
Bobs Place           111111111
Jims Place           222222222
Jims Place           333333333
Lizzys Place         444444444
Lizzys Place         444444444
Lizzys Place         555555555
```

I need the output to be...

```
Name                 Phone
--------------------------------------
Jims Place           222222222
Jims Place           333333333
Lizzys Place         444444444
Lizzys Place         555555555
```

Jims and Lizzys have multiple differing Phone lines, Bobs has multiple rows...but the same line so we dont care about those rows.

I have attempted to use COUNT() >1 but BOB would still count as 2, DISTINCT also would leave rows I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a `HAVING` clause including a query along with `GROUP BY` expression :

```
SELECT name, phone
  FROM tab t
 GROUP BY name, phone
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phone) FROM tab t2 WHERE name = t.name ) > 1
```

*P.S. Indeed it's better to use Analytic Functions if applicable for such type of questions, but we don't know your DBMS as using standard SQL.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=445e469155eb8670c924d8df5ce7b693)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get unique combination (name and phone), then at first remove duplicates and then you can use the most efficient approach in SQL server - window/analytic function, such as COUNT (with partition by name) to get correct result:

```
  select name,phone from
   (
     select name,phone,count(phone)over(partition by name)countphone from
     (
      select distinct name,phone from Table
     ) t 
   )tt where countphone>1
```

Comment: Jared Phillips, please tell, do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `select distinct` with a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct name, phone
from a
where exists (select 1 from a a2 where a2.name = a.name and a2.phone <> a.phone);
```